# How to get multiple checkboxes value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, checkbox

I am working on an admin panel.I have 3 checkboxes for permissions of 3 things. I am getting the value of checkbox and name of permission from apidata. I am having trouble updating the checkbox value and then sending it back to the api.

How can i update it? I have searched on the internet but i have not find any solution.

Here is the code.

```
const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState({
checklist:{
    isView:false,
    isEdit:false,
    isDelete:false },
incidences:{
    isView:false,
    isEdit:false,
    isDelete:false },
dashboardt:{
    isView:false,
    isEdit:false,
    isDelete:false
  }});
{PermissionList.map((item) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div className="ms-2">
                              <h6 className="mb-1 font-14">{item.permissionName}</h6>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div className="d-flex order-actions">
                            <input
                              className="form-check-input fs-4"
                              type="checkbox"
                              id={item.permissionId}
                              value={eval(`permissions.${item.permissionName}.isView`)}
                              checked={permissions.isView}
                              onChange={(e)=>{
                                setPermissions({
                                  isView:e.target.checked,
                                  isEdit:false,
                                  isDelete:false

                                })
                              }}
                              aria-label="..."
                            />
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div className="d-flex order-actions">
                            <input
                              className="form-check-input fs-4"
                              type="checkbox"
                              id={item.permissionId}
                              value={permissions.isEdit}
                              checked={permissions.isEdit}
                              onChange={(e)=>{
                                setPermissions({
                                  isView:false,
                                  isEdit:e.target.checked,
                                  isDelete:false

                                })
                              }}
                              aria-label="..."
                            />
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div className="d-flex order-actions">
                            <div className="d-flex order-actions">
                              <input
                                className="form-check-input fs-4"
                                type="checkbox"
                                
                              id={item.permissionId}
                              value={permissions.isDelete}
                              checked={permissions.isDelete}
                              onChange={(e)=>{
                                setPermissions({
                                  isView:false,
                                  isEdit:false,
                                  isDelete:e.target.checked

                                })
                              }}
                                aria-label="..."
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
```

And here is the snapshot of the component

[image]

And I want this in payload sent to api:

[
{
"groupId": 1,
"permissionId": 1,
"isView": false,
"isEdit": true,
"isDelete": true
}
]
While i get the groupId and permissionId from the state and component Id how can i get the rest of three updated values. And also how can i dynamically send it like only send that permission id whose value is updated and not send the rest of 2 or 1.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you need it to do

Answer (score 0):

There is a variant of the setter that will pass the value to a thunk function. Use that in the `onClick`, spread it to return that object but with just the one checkbox value updated.

```
onClick={setPermissions((p)=>{...p, isDelete:e.target.checked})}
```

Also, it's very bad practice to use `eval`.

```
// Change this:
value={eval(`permissions.${item.permissionName}.isView`)}

// To this:
value={permissions[item.permissionName].isView}
```

EDIT:
just make a copy of the state passed into the setter, and update the value you want to change.

```
  onClick={
    (e) => {
      setPermissions(p => {
        const prev = { ...p }
        prev.checklist.isView = e.target.checked
        return prev
      })
    }
  }
```

EDIT 2:
You can call a method onClick that will update your component's state and push up to the server. Something like this:

```
const onCheckboxChanged = async (whichProperty, whichCheckbox, checked) => {
    // update your component's state and cause component to re-render
    const updatedPermissions = {...permissions}
    updatedPermissions[whichProperty][whichCheckbox] = checked
    setPermissions(updatedPermissions)

    // you can just update the contents of your state property
    // directly and not change like the next line, but it will
    // not cause the component to re-render so your checkboxes
    // may not update.
    permissions[whichProperty][whichCheckbox] = checked

    // next you can notify server, spread the view/edit/delete
    // keys from your permissions object into the object you're
    // sending to the server.
    await pushToServer(JSON.stringify(
      [{
        "groupId": 1,
        "permissionId": getIdFromProperty(whichProperty),
        ...updatedPermissions[whichProperty]
        }]
    ))
}
```

Something like that. And your onChange will just call that function:

```
onChange={(e)=>{onCheckboxChanged(whichProperty, "checklist", e.target.checked)}}
```

EDIT 3:
What I recommend is that you add a "test" button in your UI. When you press it, it will send the payload to the server. Just hard-code the payload. Get that working. Then make 1 checkbox, and update your code so you can change the checkbox and when you press 'test' it will send that value to your server. If you want to update the server ever time a checkbox changes, then add that functionality (but with just 1 checkbox). Then add the other two checkboxes, but only 1 property. And finally, update the code to support multiple properties. Take small steps. Get just 1 part working and then expand on it. And maybe - don't even work on this issue. Just spend 3-7 hours following some tutorials and when you return you'll get this working very quickly.

Comment: I updated my question. Kindly take a look

Comment: Still not know how to get my payload object values

Comment: Hey @Dave I appreciate your answer, but now I am getting problems setting the permissionsList values in the checked object. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: get debugger working and look at the permissions object (or console.log it) to see the values are what you intend them to be. And get rid of that 'eval' and access the property as illustrated in a few places in the snippets of code from my answer.